Object moves in opposite direction from the axes
I am currently working on a model which requires an array of the same object following a curve. In order to have the array of objects facing the appropriate direction along the curve, I had to apply a 180° rotation to my Y and Z axes... And now the object acts weird.
Namely : when I move it along the X axis, it moves along the Z one (i.e vertically). When I move it along the Z axis, it moves along the X one (i.e horizontally). And when I move it along the Y axis, it moves in the opposite direction (i.e it goes left when I pull it to the right).
And I cannot, for the life of me, find how to fix this problem : I've tried applying All Transformations to reset the scale, location & rotation to 0, it didn't change anything. I tried moving the origin around, but nothing either. I have absolutely no clue what's going on.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Without seeing any screenshot where we can see the settings like Transformation Orientation, the object's rotation, the Array and Curve modifier setting etc. it is hard to tell what exactly is going on, we can only guess blindly. And are you moving the object in Object Mode or Edit Mode? And if you want the object to follow the curve, what is your goal in moving it which you cannot achieve with this weird behavior? Probably uploading your file here: https://blend-exchange.com would be best and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.
